# Async/Await not working when launched with VSC Liveserver

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, promise, async-await, axios

I use VS Code with Live Server.

I am requesting data with `Axios` from an API and having the data `console.logged` in the Chrome Console. However, I'm not getting any data back. In the Network tab, the request is sent and returns `200`, but the promise keeps on pending and does not get resolved.

Same request using exact code works well in the Chrome Console.

Why is that the code does not work when I launch it from VSCode? Do I need special extensions or something?

```
async function getPlanets() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/planets/');
    console.log(res.data);
}

getPlanets();
```

Comment: There are many, many possible reasons for your code not to work, but nobody can help if nobody can see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). (Use a promise around `setTimeout` to emulate the axios call.)

Comment: I just tried the API. The data is returned directly, not on a `data` property. So `console.log(res);` will show you the data (or `res.results` if you just want the results array). (That site seems to support CORS, since I was able to query from `localhost`.) HTH!

Comment: Side note: Since you're fairly new to this stuff, I'll just note that there's little reason for using the `axios` library these days. `fetch` is fine for most use cases. You do need to be aware of [the footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html), but other than that...

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! I see what you mean - that the data are returned directly. But if you console.log(res), there is a property called `data` which also contains the `results` array and a bunch of other properties. The planets' array should be on `res.data.results`. I've tried to console.log(res.results) and it returns `undefined`. But still, all of this works just from the Chrome Console and not locally. I will try to rewrite it with `fetch` instead to see if I manage to make it work. Thank you again!

Comment: @IlariaCallegari - Sorry, that's an `axios` thing and I was using `fetch`. Yes, it should be on `res.data` if you're using `axios`, and it is for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/aeufyq51/